# Find the probability that a rv is equal to its order statistics $P(X_i = Y_j)$

Tags: probability, statistics, order-statistics

Let $X_i$, $i=1...n$ be independent **non identically** distributed random variables and let $Y_i$ be its order statistics.

I want to find the probability that $X_i$ is equal to $Y_j$ for each i, j

$i.e., \mathbb{P}(X_i = Y_j)$.

It was easy to find the distributions of order statistics, but I cannot go further. Anyone can help?

Thanks.

Comment: The event you interested should be equivalent to the $X_i$ has a rank of $j$ among the random variables. Theoretically, you can compute the probability for each permutation and then summing those with $X_i$ exactly $j$-th rank. But this is computationally heavy. And I also wonder if the distributions of the order statistics is "easy" but tedious.

Comment: I want to compute the probability "without" computing for all permutation. I was wondering whether there exists an analytical way to compute the probability. Thanks for your comment!